# How do I remove a repository from the terminal?

Tags: apt

I have a Banshee link that is wrong and I need to remove it, how do I do it from the Terminal? I have the incorrect link, I have the correct one as well.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You would need to locate the specific lines in `/etc/apt/sources.list`

Open the sources file with some editor while using sudo, such as vim (I personally use `nano`, but you can use whatever you want):

`sudo vim /etc/apt/sources.list`

Locate the lines which contain the broken link, and remove them.  Save the files, then run `sudo apt-get update` after you save the file and close out the editor.  Your sources will be updated to work with the non-broken repositories.

Note that if the lines don't show up in `/etc/apt/sources.list` then they'll exist in other files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` in which case you'll have to go through the files in that directory and comment out the broken source definition there.

Comment: Note: it is possible that the repositories are not only written in the single file /etc/apt/sources.list, but distributed in several files (one per repository) inside the directory /etc/apt/sources.list.d/

Comment: True, but the first place to look would be `/etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: this work for me, thank you

Answer (score 4):

If you need to manage PPAs then this question is for you:

- [How can PPAs be removed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307/how-can-ppas-be-removed)