# Remove package repository

Tags: apt, package-management, software-center

I must have a package repository listed that I can't reach and get the following error when I run `apt-get update`:

```
Failed to fetch https://<my.favorite.cran.mirror>/bin/linux/ubuntu/trusty/Packages  Could not resolve host: <my.favorite.cran.mirror>
```

But I don't know how to remove it because it is not in my software sources list when I open up the Ubuntu Software Center. Is there a way to remove this with the terminal?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can PPAs be removed?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/307/how-can-ppas-be-removed)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove a repository from the terminal?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/36142/how-do-i-remove-a-repository-from-the-terminal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the specific PPA, type:

```
 sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:thenameoftheppa/ppa
```

Then, update it with:

```
 sudo apt-get update
```

This removes the PPA permanently and if you were to install it again, you'd have to use the code like you haven't installed it.

Comment: Depending on which version of Ubuntu you are running.

Comment: I am running 14.04

Comment: Then you should be able to remove the repository.